# According Advaita philosophy, can the formless Absolute Brahman see, speak, hear and smell?

Tags: upanishads, atma, brahman, advaita

In the [Kena Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad/d/doc122448.html) following is said about the Absolute Brahman(not Atma...if Atma and Brahman are same then probably I have asked this question before. But in my opinion Absolute Brahman is a state of pure bliss. Atma merges into Brahman.):

> ‘What speech cannot reveal, but what reveals speech—know thou That
>   alone as Brahman, and not this (anything objective)that people worship
>   here.’
>
> ‘What hearing fails to hear, but what hears hearing— know thou That
>   alone as Brahman, and not this that people worship here.’
>
> ‘What smell does not reveal, but what reveals smell— know thou That
>   alone as Brahman, and not this that people worship here.’

As per my understanding, the formless Absolute, although without ear, is capable hearing; although without nose, is capable of smelling; although without mouth, is capable of speech.

My question is: Can the formless Absolute Brahman see, speak, hear and smell without eyes, mouth, ears and nose?

Comment: Speaking is duality so Nirguna Brahman of Advaita cannot speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes & No**.

Verses posted in Qn are already referred in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20954/1049) from Gita:

> **सर्वेन्द्रियगुणाभासं** सर्वेन्द्रियविवर्जितम्। असक्तं सर्वभृच्चैव **निर्गुणं** गुणभोक्तृ च।।
>   BG 13.15 - **Reflecting through the senses, [yet] devoid of all the senses**; disinterested; the sustainer of all; Without 3 modes, and the consumer of 3 modes

The *Nirguna Brahman (Atman)* which , doesn't have any senses, yet all the consumption done by our senses reaches to 'that' only -- who is devoid & disinterested.

Comment: Do you agree that Absolute Brahman performs the actions of the senses?

Comment: @DheerajVerma, again yes & no. "Absolute Brahman" (Atman) is never an actor (i.e. performer of actions). Refer [BG 3.27, 5.8-9](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20347/1049). All the actions happen under the influence of *Prakruti*. However *Prakruti* itself is spawned under the control of "Absolute Brahman". Refer [BG 9.8](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19458/1049). :-)