# On the nature of Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita

I want to know whether

1. Lord Krishna was a realized person but at birth born like us normal creatures (because he says many times that=*he was aware of the divine nature of the soul and his previous births, but Arjuna was not-so is he referring to him being a normal human and then getting enlightened or enlightened by birth*

or

2. Lord Krishna was aware of his divine nature and was God descended directly.
   Also then, did Lord Vishnu disappear from his abode and appear on Earth, or did Lord Narayana divide himself into one for his abode and one for Earth?
3. Who is the "I" in the Gita? Krishna as in himself descended in his body or the soul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krishna was already a "realized". He's the ever-realized for he's Vishnu himself, or Krishna (of Goloka) himself.

This is what he says in the  Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa when he "departs" from his mortal coils when hit by the hunter Jarā.

> [ŚB 11.30.39](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/30/39/)
>
> श्रीभगवानुवाच
>
> मा भैर्जरे त्वमुत्तिष्ठ काम एष कृतो हि मे । याहि त्वं मदनुज्ञात:
> स्वर्गं सुकृतिनां पदम् ॥ ३९ ॥
>
> > Sri Krishna said: My dear Jarā, do not fear. Please get up. **What has
> > been done is actually My own desire.** With My permission, go now to the
> > abode of the pious, the spiritual world.

- So the answer to your question 1 & 2(a) is, he was a realized person.
- As regards question 2(b) Vishnu being present in his abode, when he descended as Krishna, yes. He was very much present in the Svetadvipa - Ksheer Sagara, as we can see in this excerpt from  Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa where Krishna (along with Arjuna) meets Vishnu.

> [ŚB 10.89.57](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/89/57/)
>
> ववन्द आत्मानमनन्तमच्युतो जिष्णुश्च तद्दर्शनजातसाध्वस: । तावाह भूमा
> परमेष्ठिनां प्रभु- र्बद्धाञ्जली सस्मितमूर्जया गिरा ॥ ५७ ॥
>
> > **Lord Kṛṣṇa offered homage to Himself in this boundless form, and
> > Arjuna, astonished at the sight of Lord Mahā-Viṣṇu,** bowed down as
> > well. Then, as the two of them stood before Him with joined palms, the
> > almighty Mahā-Viṣṇu, supreme master of all rulers of the universe,
> > smiled and spoke to them in a voice full of solemn authority.

Further,

- For question 3, it's well established that Krishna is Vishnu himself, and/ or the Original person of the Spiritual Goloka.

For the "I" in Gita, refer these -

- [Is there any reference that Krishna was connected to Brahman while speaking Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30278/is-there-any-reference-that-krishna-was-connected-to-brahman-while-speaking-gita)
- [According to Bhagvad Gita, Lord Krishna is the ultimate God. So why are there other beliefs in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18332/according-to-bhagvad-gita-lord-krishna-is-the-ultimate-god-so-why-are-there-ot/18335#18335)

Answer (score 2):

The nature of Krishna was divine. This can be deduced from the events related to his childhood. He was born in jail, but events lead to his escape and miraculously crossing over stormy Jamuna rive. During his childhood he performed several miraculous deeds, including giving the Vishvaroop darshan to Jasoda maiya!

Answer (score 2):

Sri Maha Vishnu takes the form a body to come to Earth ( as body is very much required to live on Earth). Bhagwan (Narayana) can take many avatars, he is omnipotent which means he can take several avatars,

Prahlada Charitram says Narashimha was staying in every pillar of the house of Prahlada as he didn't know which pillar will be shown by him which implies he can stay everywhere at the same time

Krishna's soul is Maha Vishnu and I refers to himself, the supreme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Krishna is the Supreme lord of the universe -

> *He is without birth and death, of radiant splendour, the **Creator of the universe** and the Lord of all! Indeed, he who is the invisible
> cause of all, who knows no deterioration, who is the **all-pervading**
> soul, the centre round which everything moves, the substance in which
> the three attributes of Sattva, Rajas and Tamas co-inhere, the
> **universal soul**, the immutable, the material out of which has been created this universe, the Creator himself, the controlling lord, the
> **invisible dweller in every object**, progenitor of this universe of five elements, who is united with the six high attributes, is the
> Pranava or **Om of the Vedas**, is infinite, incapable of being moved
> by any force save his own will, illustrious, the embodiment of the
> mode of life called Sannyasa, **of who floated on the waters before the
> creation,**** who is the source whence has sprung this mighty frame, who
> is the great combiner, **the uncreate**, the invisible essence of all,
> the great immutable, bereft of those attributes that are knowable by
> the senses, who is the universe itself, **without beginning, birth,
> and decay,**— is possessed of infinite wealth, that Grandsire of all
> creatures, became incarnate in the race of the Andhaka-Vrishnis for
> the increase of virtue.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4025.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes Lord Krishna knew he was an avatar of Lord Vishnu.:

> Listen, O Partha, to this secret and ancient history as it is, O sinless one! **I have four forms, eternally engaged as I am in protecting the worlds. Dividing my own Self, I ordain the good of the worlds. One form of mine, staying on the earth, is engaged in the practice of ascetic austerities. Another beholdeth the good and the evil deeds in the world. My third form, coming into the world of men, is engaged in action. My fourth form lieth down in sleep for a thousand years. The form of mine which awaketh from sleep at the end of a thousand years, granteth, upon awakening, excellent boons to persons deserving of them.**
>
> - MBH Drona Parva Section 27.

2. I think my 1st verse only answered this still here another one. Lord Vishnu always rwmains in Vaikuntha even after taking avatars.

> "**The blessed Krishna continued** ... I stood all the while, supporting myself upon one foot and with my arms also raised upwards, and foregoing sleep all the while I then beheld, O Bharata, in the firmament an effulgence that seemed to be as dazzling as that of a thousand Suns combined together. . . . The puissant Indra, **Bhagawan Vishnu**, the sons of Aditi, and the Grandsire Brahma, all uttered, in the presence of Bhava, the Rathantara Saman.
>
> - Mahabharata , Anushasana Parva, ie., In Book 13, Chapter 15 verses 1 to 51.

3. "I" in the Gita is the Antaryami of Krishna.:

> ‘Vasudeva said, ‘I made thee listen to truths that are regarded as mysteries. I imparted to thee truths that are eternal. Verily, I discoursed to thee on Religion in its true form and on all the eternal regions. It is exceedingly disagreeable to me to learn that thou didst not, from folly, receive what I imparted. The recollection of all that I told thee on that occasion will not come to me now. Without doubt, O son of Pandu, thou art destitute of faith and thy understanding is not good. **It is impossible for me, O Dhananjaya, to repeat, in detail, all that I said on that occasion. That religion (about which I discoursed to thee then as gita) is more than sufficient for understanding Brahma. I cannot discourse on it again in detail. I discoursed to thee on Supreme Brahma, having concentrated myself in Yoga’**”. (MBH 14:16:5-13a).

> **The blessed Krishna said,** 'Bowing my head with great joy unto that mass of energy and effulgence, **I said these words unto the great Bhagavan Shiva, with a heart filled with gladness,--**
>
> 1. Firmness in virtue, (dharme dṛḍhatvaṃ)
> 2. The slaughter of foes in battle,(yudhi śatrughātaṃ)
> 3. The highest fame,(yaśas tathāgryaṃ )
> 4. The greatest might, (paramaṃ balaṃ)
> 5. **Devotion to Yoga, (yogapriyatvaṃ)**
> 6. **Thy adjacence, (ava saṃnikarṣaṃ)** and
> 7. Hundreds upon hundreds of children, (vṛṇe sutānāṃ ca śataṃ śatāni)
>
> **these are the boons I solicit of thee,--So be it,--said Sankara.**
>
> - Mahabharata, Anushasan parva Book 13, chapter 16, Verses 1 to 3.

> “That Vishnu who knows every thing, who has greatest qualities, who cannot be won over by anybody, who has special holy sight, and who is greatly resplendent, **always sees and remains connected (viz meditate on) him (Rudra) by his eyes of yoga”.** (MBH 13:14:9).

> “I am the Soul, O son of Pandu, of all the worlds, of all the universe. **Rudra, again, is my Soul.** It is for this that I always adore him. If I do not adore the auspicious and boon-giving Isana nobody would then adore my own self.”
>
> - The Shanti Parva (Chapter 342) of the Mahabharata.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..