# Do non-Advaita Vedanta philosophies also believe that buddhi is part of Prakruti/Pradhana?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vishishtadvaita, dvaita, achintya-bheda-abheda

Do Vedanta philosophies other than Advaita also believe that *Buddhi* is part of *Prakriti/Pradhana* and not part of/is individual self? If yes, how do liberated beings think in Vaikuntha?

Answer (score 1):

The status of *Buddhi* (intellect) is ambiguous from the *Prakruti* (nature) perspective. It can be interpreted both the ways -- if *Buddhi* belongs to *Prakruti* or not?

#### Yes

*Sattva, Rajas, Tamas* as 3 modes are born out of the *Prakruti*. According to these modes, an entity may have *SAtvika, RAjasika, TAmasika -- Buddhi-s* [[BG 18.30-32]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20347/1049). Which means *Buddhi* is influenced by the *Prakruti*.

#### No

*Prakruti* attracts the *Mann* (mind) & *Indriya* (senses) for getting a new body after every death [[BG 15.7-9]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15356/1049). And also, *Buddhi* is said to be beyond *Mann*. [[BG 3.42]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20347/1049)

For ease of understanding, I often compare *Buddhi* to *Purusha* (the soul or *Jiva*) or contained by *Purusha* [[see this]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10799/1049).

---

#### *Vaikuntha*

The terminology of *vaikuntha* being the ultimate destination, is a *Vaishnava* philosophy, especially the followers of lord Krishna. In popular culture, Krishna's playtime happens in "Vaikuntha" & in Gita at [[BG 8.21]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13950/1049), Krishna refers, 'once reached at "My ultimate place", one doesn't return'. Hence, may be the innocent devotees would have associated "Vaikuntha" as "place", where Moksha happens.

Now, if we think that *Vaikuntha* as a "place", where certain *Jiva*-s "reside", then it's not Moksha. Moksha is beyond space ("place") and time ("reside").
In such case, *Vaikuntha* is equivalent to *Brahma-loka*, the highest of all the planes/worlds. Here the soul may get Moksha or may return as well. While "My ultimate place" (i.e. Moksha), is a point of "no return", "absolute non-existence".

> BG 8.16 - All planes along with BrahM-loka are repetitive, O Arjuna. But reaching "Me", O son of Kunti, the rebirth doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but you are giving your personal understanding, I am asking for views of non advaita vedanta schools. They treat vaikuntha/parampada/etc as real place. For example shrivaishnavism has elaborate descriptions of Shriman Narayana sitting on conch flanked by Laxmi, Bhudevi, Niladevi, nitya suris etc. One of the criticism Madhvacharya levelled against advaita was their nishkriya idea of liberation violated scriptural statements which say liberated being sports, enjoys himself etc.